# Php not working with nginx

Tags: web-server, php, troubleshooting

So I tried following this [guide](https://www.pestmeester.nl/), but seems to fail at *[this](https://www.pestmeester.nl/index.html#8.5)* step. When accessing the /index.php my browser(both chromium and firefox) downloaded the page as a file, then I decided to delete the file from sites-available and begin from the default file again, now it doesnt download the site but just shows a plain white site with no source code.

I am pretty sure its just me who screwed something up in the code. Here is my nginx conf from sites-available:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /data/randomsite10101.org/www;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name randomsite10101.org.local randomsite10101.org;
    error_log /data/randomsite10101.org/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /data/randomsite10101.org/logs/access.log;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

New config:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;
    error_log /data/randomsite10101.org/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /data/randomsite10101.org/logs/access.log;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /data/randomsite10101.com/www;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name randomsite10101.org;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #}
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }   


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/randomsite10101.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/randomsite10101.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m; # managed by Certbot
ssl_session_timeout 1440m; # managed by Certbot

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; # managed by Certbot

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA"; # managed by Certbot



    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

[David Cullen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/46953/david-cullen) asked me for the output from `ls -hl /data/sitename.com/www/`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  8 Jan  9 04:10 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     21 Jan  9 04:20 index.php
```

Then I tried to chown the folder to `www-data` with following command:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /data/randomsite.com/www/
```

And my output is now:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  8 Jan  9 04:10 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 21 Jan  9 04:20 index.php
```

But it's still not working.

David asked me to remove the index.html, and with only index.php it still shows an empty page.

He asked me to comment some line out aswell and edit my index.php file, both tings done and still empty page.

Comment: Your code belongs in your question not on a third party site. This is designed to prevent link rot. Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I really tried doing that. But some code kept staying below and over the table.
Here is an extra link to the config from github: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8b275379cd54e43e35c9977896f1aac

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `index.php` to look like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      phpinfo();
    ?>
  <body>
<html>
```

Apparently, the `<html>` and `<body>` tags are important. I got the idea from this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17778264/3657941).

Also, I had to comment out the line

```
# listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

I was getting the following error message:

```
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I don't have IPv6 enabled on the network interface on the Raspberry Pi I am using.

**Original Answer**

Try simplifying your PHP `location` match to

```
location ~ \.php$
```

Also, make sure you have `php5` and `php5-fpm` installed:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep php
```

If you see `php-fpm` instead of `php5-fpm`, you probably have `php7` installed. If you have `php7` installed, you will need to change your `location` stanza:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help.
I have php5 installed, gets no errors when restarting nginx anymore.
I tried to edit the location line to what you suggested, but still shows an empty webpage, according to the guide it should output a pile of information about my php config due to the index.php site with following content:"<?php phpinfo(); ?>"

Comment: What is the output of `ls -hl /data/randomsite10101.org/www`? Put the output in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Done. Should I edit my nginx config file in the question aswell? Atm. It's simply
location ~ \.php$

And I checked for php version, I got php5-fpm installed along with alot other php5.

Comment: I added my new config, since i added lets encrypt certificates and your location string instead of the original. Furthermore i noticed that in the new config file root is /var/www/html; where it was /data/randomsite/www before. I tested if the /data/randomsite10101/www worked, It didnt.

Comment: I recommend using the simple nginx configuration until you get `phpinfo` working. I have updated my answer. I was wrong about `index.html`.

Comment: I already tried both of your suggestions. Tested it both with /var/www/html/ as root and /data/Rs10101/www as root, which I made it stay as,

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16887296/7392716) answer helped me and resolved it.

I replaced

```
include fastcgi_params;
```

with

```
include fastcgi.conf;
```

And restarted php with

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

and nginx with

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Last command helped me alot during all the edits, because it's outputting the error and eventually linenumber.

Thank you very much for trying to help me [David.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/46953/david-cullen)